# Add hyperlink to create New record as a Column Page Block Table

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a table which shows list of records(position__c). Now i wanted to add a column which will be a hyperlink/button that will create a new child record(Job_Application__c) of the record displayed in that row...

eg. in table first row refer to a position record (which is a parent record) and clicking on the hyperlink should open a create new Job_Application record (child record) tab,

How can i do this in apex page block table....I have worked on Custom button and links and know about URL hacking but i am trying to create it a table for the first time so thanks for the knowledge..

Comment: can you share whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to do this in standard salesforce and note the url that is generated.  This url will have a parameter that looks like _lkid='xxx' which references the parent record and the lookup field that you will need to populate.  In your datatable you will need to create this url on button click.  Might want to store the lookup field value reference in a custom setting.